# MPAndroidchart how to display label inside MarkerView?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) and I want to show values of xlabes and ylabes with markerview, I have shown the value of y-axis. And I don't konw how to show the value of x-axis(xVals), Can u show me how to do this or give me some tutorial links? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you just hand your array of x-values to the `MarkerView`.

Then in the `refreshContent(...)` method:

```
@Override
public void refreshContent(Entry e, Highlight highlight) {
    String xValue = xValuesArray.get((int) e.getX());        
}
```

Comment: I just don't know how to hand my array of x-values to the MarkerView, I have 4 barchart in my activity, how to use xValuesArray?  Thanks a lot

Comment: Just add a setter method to your implementation of the `MarkerView`. Nothing more basic than that :-)

Comment: I cannot find `e.getXIndex()` in 3.0.0